# Load controller located in a partial view when application runs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

According to a previous question I made and was solved, I wanted to emit an event from a service a be listened by a controller ([$emit or $broadcast events from service and listen them in a controller (or several)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013883/emit-or-broadcast-events-from-service-and-listen-them-in-a-controller-or-seve)).

My issue now is that I have a main controller who is able to listen service events, but I want to click a button in order to load a partial view which contains its own controller which listen events.

As I don't know how can I load this controller in the first application load, I miss some events emitted by the service.

Anyone has any tip for this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `ng-show` around the partial view and clicking the button would just reveal it. It would give you the same user experience.

Alternatively you could create a mechanism to queue the events that your parent controller has received and after you create the child partial view, re-broadcast them down to the child controller. (Note: I've never done this before just theorizing)